# How to Create a new table and check wether it exists (and if so delete all the content) Without using IF

Tags: sql, db2, create-table

I want to create a Table with some columns. If however the table of this name already exists, i want to delete the content of the table.

I can only use code that works in an .sql file, because the test functions just grab the code from those files. The database is a DB2LUW. Now i tried different ideas with DELETE and CHECK but it didn't work. And "IF" is not recognized, therefore i could not use all the other options i found on here.

```
CREATE TABLE KundenKontaktDaten (

        Kunden_Nr INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        Twitter_Id VARCHAR(40),
        Google_Id BIGINT,
        Facebook_Id BIGINT,
        Skype_Id VARCHAR(64),
        Telefonnummer VARCHAR(50)
)
```

Comment: you need to say what version and what Db2 platform you are using

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a current version of Db2...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE KundenKontaktDaten (

        Kunden_Nr INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        Twitter_Id VARCHAR(40),
        Google_Id BIGINT,
        Facebook_Id BIGINT,
        Skype_Id VARCHAR(64),
        Telefonnummer VARCHAR(50)
) ON REPLACE DELETE ROWS
```

Comment: thanks, its not working unfortunately. however i was able to work around it implementing parts of it in java and then catching the exceptioncode it throws when the table already exists